# Is it possible to use editor.tokenColorCustomizations in a VSCode theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

1.15 added the ability to theme general aspects of the syntax scopes, I'm trying to simplify a theme with the generic tokens ('comments', 'variables' etc.), however `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` doesn't seem to work. Is there a variation that works or is it not intended for themes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, those "generic tokens" are specific to the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting (meaning you can't use them in a theme). They are mapped to TmLanguage scopes as follows:

```json
comments: 'comment',
strings: 'string',
keywords: 'keyword',
numbers: 'constant.numeric',
types: 'entity.name.type',
functions: 'entity.name.function',
variables: 'variable'
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/29393/files#diff-fcf8acf0156463f17f7fa7ed78c3b7e8R27